# Is the Runed Lexicon of any use or value after completing Discerning the Transmundane

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I gave the runed lexicon to Septimus Signus, after Hermaeus Mora killed him I took back the runed lexicon. Is there any point or use for keeping this item, other than some slight sentimental value?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no use for the Runed Lexicon after the quest is complete. It is supposed to disappear after the quest is complete but there is a bug which may mean it does now, If you loot it from Septus' corpse, you may not be able to drop it. If you are playing on the PC, you can get rid of it with the following console command:

```
player.removeitem 3a3dd 1
```

If you're on a console, there's no known fix for the bug.

Answer (score -3):

Wrong! There are several dwemer ruins that need it to open special doors, containers etc

Comment: Do you have a source for that info?

Comment: You might be thinking of the focusing crystal used in the [Revealing the Unseen](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Revealing_the_Unseen) quest.

Comment: He's thinking of the [Attunement Sphere](https://elderscrolls.fandom.com/wiki/Attunement_Sphere) provided by [Septimus Sigmus](https://elderscrolls.fandom.com/wiki/Septimus_Signus) at the same time as the player is handed the (blank) Runed Lexicon, so it's an easy mistake to make.